# Is it possible to generate an APK file from a base64String API response call?

Tags: android, web-services, kotlin, apk

I'm currently working on a solution how to update and install APK file programmatically - very similar  like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26293449/12083845) issue. My app **doesn't use** Google Services.

For updating purposes, APK-files with ascending versions are stored on an internal server and a C# Web service returns the **latest** version of the APK file.

I do this with Retrofit2:

```
    @Streaming
    @GET("/ws/webservice.svc/getUpdate")
    fun getUpdate(
        @Query("Programm") program: String,
        @Query("version") version: String,
        @Query("test") test: Boolean
    ): Single<String>
```

and LiveData:

```
override fun getUpdate() {
        disposables += api.getUpdate(
            program = context.getString(R.string.app_name),
            version = context.getString(R.string.app_version),
            test = isTest
        )
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeBy(
                onSuccess = {
                    liveData.value = GetUpdate(it)
                },
                onError = {
                    liveData.value = Error("Error getUpdate: " + it.message)
                }
            )
    }
```

The problem that I'm facing, is that the response of that API call (which means - the latest APK file) has a **base64String** representation like shown in the image below - this is for example only a part of the server response when the API call is made in browser.

[image: APK file as String]

Is it somehow possible to generate a "real" APK file from this String representation after downloading it, so after that I can probably be able to install it on the device? I know that this is weird, but the customer wants me to re-use the same web service for this purposes.

I found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704581/sending-image-in-base64-string-and-receiving-in-webservice-via-ksoap). How can be this done in Kotlin? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

MVVM with LiveData:

```
    override fun getUpdate() {
        disposables += api.getUpdate(
            program = context.getString(R.string.app_name) + ".apk",
            version = context.getString(R.string.app_version),
            test = isTest
        )
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map(::decodeToAPK)
            .subscribe({
                liveData.value = GetUpdate 
            }, {
                liveData.value = Error("Error getUpdate: " + it.message)
            })
    }


    private fun decodeToAPK(base64String: String) {

        val byteArrayAPK = Base64.decode(base64String, Base64.DEFAULT)

        val file =
            File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "yourApp.apk")
        try {
            val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
            fileOutputStream.write(byteArrayAPK)
            fileOutputStream.flush()
            fileOutputStream.close()
        } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
            Log.d(null, "error writing APK")
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
   }

   sealed class SomeAction : Action {
     data class Error(val message: String) : SomeAction()
     object GetUpdate : SomeAction()
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to decode the `base64` into a `ByteArray` then write the bytes to a location with the postfix `.apk`.  What you have is a `String` where the `bytes` are `encoded` using the `base64` encoding scheme.

Since your using `kotlin` you might what to look here to get the `ByteArray!`[1] from the `String`.  Then just ensure the file you write has `.apk` extension.

[1] https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/util/Base64.Decoder#decode(kotlin.String)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am on the way to implement the solution of this issue and I'll post it here as soon as possible.